# IOS integrated unity 4.6.3 project(64-bit && IL2CPP). Appear the following such a mistake, how to fix it?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I want to add Unity to an existing ios Project,I have matched all the configuration of the two project, and import the frameworks. 
I set Other Linker Flags : -weak_framework; -weak-lSystem; CoreMotion. just like the Unity Project.
and the error is：
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreMotion'
when I deleted "CoreMotion" in Other Linker Flags, error changes:
ld: framework not found -weak-lSystem

how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the order of the flags are important

It should be in this order : 
-weak_framework
CoreMotion
-weak-lSystem;